# I need to add custom buttons on Salesforce1 Compact Layouts

Tags: custom-button, compact-layout

I am using Conga Composer for merging fields of the Lead record and creating a template.But that button is not visible on Ipad, most probably because no compact Layout is created so far.But how is it possible to add a custom button on the page Layout for Salesforce1 compact layout.

Answer (score 0):

The approach for Salesforce1 is a little different as you need to configure a Global Publisher Action in conjunction with your custom button on the Lead.  Here's an article from the Conga support site around configuration of [Conga Composer for Salesforce1](https://support.getconga.com/Conga_Composer/Composer_Essentials/Composer_for_Salesforce1).